# Macro multiple worksheets and filter all sheets data with selected date range

Tags: excel, vba

How to filter multiple sheets of data within the date range. I cannot find a solution. single button it needs to filter all sheets data.

```
Sub ApplyFilter()
    Dim wsDL As Worksheet
    Dim wsABC As Worksheet
    Dim rngAD As Range
    Dim wsO() As Worksheet
    wsO = Array(Google, Bing, Yahoo, Facebook, Amazon)
    Set wsABC = wsO
    Set wsDL = Sheets("DateList")
    Set rngAD = wsABC.Range("AllDates")

    'update the list of dates
    wsDL.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.ClearContents
    'rngAD.Offset(-1, 0).Resize(rngAD.Rows.Count + 1).Select
    rngAD.AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:="", _
        CopyToRange:=wsDL.Range("A1"), Unique:=True
    wsDL.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort _
        Key1:=wsDL.Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

    'filter the list
    wsABC.Range("Database").AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _
        CriteriaRange:=wsABC.Range("G1:H2"), Unique:=False  
End Sub
```

Comment: Activate `Option Explicit` and you will see your first issues: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

Comment: It’d help if you post a screenshot of your data

Comment: yes I added a screenshot please check the image

Comment: Did you activate `Option Explicit`? It will show your errors then. You cannot wait for us to fix your code. Please [edit] and update your code after you fixed these errors.